# ifconfig sets wrong broadcast until ran again

Tags: networking, ethernet, interface, ifconfig

This issue is very confusing for me. `ifconfig` sets a different broadcast address than specified, until I run the same command again.

I'm trying to change the eth0 interface:

```
inet addr:172.23.5.1  Bcast:172.23.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

---

I then run `ifconfig eth0 broadcast 172.23.6.255 netmask 255.255.255.0 172.23.6.1`

*(note how `Bcast` is now `.255.255` instead of the specified `.6.255`.)*:

```
inet addr:172.23.6.1  Bcast:172.23.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
```

When I run the same command again, the `Bcast` is as specified:

```
inet addr:172.23.6.1  Bcast:172.23.6.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

---

1. Why is this happening?
2. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you don't need to specify `broadcast`. The `broadcast` address is the last address in subnet. The network mask already specifies the range of the subnet. When you configure an interface, you may set the IP address and network mask only.

The order of the parameters in your command is wrong.

You tell your NIC to set `broadcast` and `netmask` before `ip address`. That's why you run into this problem.

`ifconfig` sets `broadcast` and `netmask` and **after that** sets the `ip address`.

IP address `172.23.6.1` is `B class` of address, more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address), and the default network mask is `255.255.0.0`. You have to set your broadcast to `172.16.255.255` before setting the IP address.

---

With the right order of parameters you'll not have that problem.

```
ifconfig ethX xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.yyy netmask yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

or

```
ifconfig ethX  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx netmask yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

You don't need to specify the `broadcast`

Comment: don't you mean `ifconfig ethX xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx netmask yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy  broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.yyy` ?

Comment: No, you don't must setup `bcast`. Only set `ip` and `netmask`

Comment: You said the order of argument was wrong but specified the same wrong order. And you can specify broadcast if you need to

Comment: first: `ifconfig ethX xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.yyy netmask yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy` order is `ip address`, `bcast` then `netmask` Second command don't have `bcast`.  In you command `ifconfig eth3 broadcast 172.23.6.255 netmask 255.255.255.0 172.23.6.1` order is `bcast`, `netmask` thn `ip` .